# Why does Poisson's ratio always have the axial strain as the denominator?

Tags: materials, structural-analysis, stresses, measurements, manufacturing-engineering

[image: Why can't we divide the lateral by the axial strain? Why does the axial strain always have to be the denominator? Would it matter if I was careless and accidently switched them around?]

Why can't we divide the lateral by the axial strain? Why does the axial strain always have to be the denominator? Would it matter if I was careless and accidently switched them around?

Comment: Will you get the same answer if 5/1 or 1/5? It is called Poissons ratio because he defined it that way.

Comment: Think of it as the ratio of the strain in the direction perpendicular to the applied force and the strain in the direction of the applied force.

Answer (score 1):

Poisson's ratio is defined in the case of uniaxial tensile testing. As such the x axis is in the direction of the loading, while the y and z  axis are transverse.

In **isotropic** materials it doesn't make any difference which axis the material is tested.

However for **anisotropic** (i.e material that don't behave in the same way in all directions), there are usually defined 3 Poisson's ratios:

- $v_{xy}$
- $v_{yz}$
- $v_{zx}$

(that implies that $v_{ij} = v_{ji}$).